# Tweaking dataframe based on comparison between two of the columns

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data = """date   actual  corrected   aging          
"2015-09-01"    71.9      71.9     4 
"2015-09-06"    71.6      71       3
"2015-09-11"    71.3      71       2
"2015-09-12"    64.5      64.5     9
"2015-09-21"    72.2      72.2     3
"""

df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
```

I need to find min of aging when `actual` is equal to `corrected`.

My expected output is:

```
data = """date   actual  corrected   aging    min_aging          
"2015-09-01"    71.9      71.9     4            3
"2015-09-06"    71.6      71       3            3
"2015-09-11"    71.3      71       2            3
"2015-09-12"    64.5      64.5     9            3
"2015-09-21"    72.2      72.2     3            3
"""
df_expected = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
```

This is how I am approaching it:

```
df_condition = df[df.actual == df.corrected]
min_a = min(df_condition.aging)
df_condition['min_aging'] = min_a
```

is there any better way?

Comment: The first two lines of your approach are ok, but not the assignment of the variable min_a.
Have a look to pandas .loc and .iloc https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

Comment: The last row should be `df['min_aging'] = min_a`, i.e., assigning to the original dataframe and not `df_condition`?

Comment: @Shaido Yes!........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.min.html) to compact the code to a single line:

```py
df['min_aging'] = df.loc[df['actual'] == df['corrected'], 'aging'].min()
```

Note that you should assign back to `df` and not `df_condition`.